# Need help getting this button up and working CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

--Struggling to figure out why the button is not showing up on my website--
--I am trying to get an animated button to change animations when my mouse hovers over it--I'll worry about linking the button to something at a different time but I mean for instance if I wanted to link it to twitter or something how would I go about doing that?--

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: .1px;
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f7f7f7;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

button :hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #a22274;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #a22274;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}

button :active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<button>Example</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

the css selectors can't have spaces, so

```css
button :hover //wrong
button:hover // right
```

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: .1px;
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f7f7f7;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #a22274;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #a22274;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
    <button><a href="twitter.com/TheOnlyDecipher">Twitter page</a></button> <button><a href="Contact.html">Contact Information</a></button> <button><a href="points.html">Points of Interest</a></button>
    <button><a href="Learning.html">Learning notes</a></button> <button><a href="Beebs.html">Notes for Wife</a></button> <br />
    <br />
</p>
```

Comment: How would I go about centering the button on screen?

Comment: i've eddited and put button on center

Comment: I am trying to space out the buttons it works otherwise just trying to get some space and or padding between them<p align="center" >
  <button><a href="https://twitter.com/TheOnlyDecipher">Twitter page</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Information</a></button>

  <button> <a href="points.html">Points of Interest</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Learning.html">Learning notes</a></button>

  <button> <a href="Beebs.html">Notes for Wife</a></button>


<br><br>
</p>

Comment: @TheOnlyDecipher you can use padding between buttons, but i recommend that you create a new question.

Comment: i've eddited with spacement, i use margin tag on button, if i helped you, can you mark question as solved?